# Deleted System Reserved partition, ubuntu won't boot live!

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

I recently removed ubuntu 20.04 from a dual-boot environment with windows 10, and successfully got windows as the only OS back. I intended to use ubuntu live from a USB. But mistakenly I deleted the System reserved partition from my hard drive. I think this may have removed some integral parts of the kernel as I am unable to use any Linux distro live as the error "No kernel found" pops up while booting. The bootloader is fine as windows boots up and grub has been removed completely (installed while dual-booting and then removed successfully). Can anyone help me fix it?

P.S. - On an different context, I think this is the reason my Windows 10 is unable to detect driver based hardware and cant install apps from official store as it can't recognize even whether my pc is x64 based or x86 or recognize my display, processor etc.

Comment: An Ubuntu LiveUSB does not use *anything* on the had drive (that's the whole point of it!) You can boot a LiveUSB without any storage device on the system at all, which makes it a handy testing tool. If booting from your LiveUSB results in "no kernel found," then it seems likely that you have mis-made your LiveUSB.

Comment: The system reserved partition is a Microsoft thing. It’s not used by Ubuntu.